# ExpressJS NodeJS not updating server files

Tags: node.js, express, server, hosting, digital-ocean

I have a server running NodeJs and expressjs.

It was serving a static website through port 80 fine with the majority of the content and static files being served from a public directory.

I made changes on my personal computer where I created my application (things like changing type and copy and stylesheets etc)

I then went and deleted the folder on my server where I was hosting the nodejs and expressjs app.

I restart pm2 and then for some reason even though I deleted the original website I am still being served the original public website files mixed with some of my newly uploaded files.  I deleted all of those so I am confused with how or where it is getting these files I deleted.  I physically deleted the app from the server but it's as if I never did.  I also restarted pm2 several times.

To be clear I see some of the changes I made but I'm still seeing content that I thought I deleted.  When you delete an application from a Digital Ocean nodejs server does it cache files somewhere?

Anyhelp with why I am still seeing old files I deleted would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), it will restart your application every time you made a change

Comment: I'll give that a try I'm not sure I have that installed. thank you I will let you know if it works

Comment: It didn't work same thing.   Do you know if files are cached somewhere?

Comment: It may work in your enviornment and it does in my local enviornment as well.  This is why I am asking on a forum.  When I post on digital ocean it doesn't work.  The files are being cached somewhere and I am trying to ask someone who has experience with nodejs or express where that place is so I can clear it out. I understand that it should work and again on my local machine it does.  It just doesn't on digital ocean

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  I'm stuck with the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me it might be a browser caching issue. Make sure to clear your browser cache to assure you’re always dealing with “live” results.

If this doesn’t help, the only other possibility I can think of is that when you “restart pm2”, you failed to gracefully stop the previous run of your program, perhaps by killing `pm2` with a CTRL-C, which could leave a spawned sub-process running.

Use the version of the `ps` or equivalent for your particular operating system to assure you don’t have any of these unmanaged or “dangling” server processes still running.

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a long time and I see there is not so many answers. I had the same problem yesterday, I uploaded new files and my website was still showing old files. My solution was to flush my public DNS cache here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache